# fetching rows from multiple users and displaying them ordered by date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a function that will fetch users from a subscribe table. 
Those users are then used to fetch their individual articles and showing them in an ordered fashion.

I've managed to do it halfway. It will fetch a user, then outputting the users articles. But it will take one user at a time. I'm searching for a way to select all users in my subscribe table and fetching them all, so i can display them simultaneously, but ordered by date.

The tables :

---

```
**Subscribe :** 
Lastviewed ( datetime ) 
Uniqueuser ( userid )
Subscription ( subscribed users id)
```

---

```
**Article:**
date_posted ( datetime )
uniqueuser ( users id)
```

---

This is what i got :

```
$sesname = $_SESSION['full_name'];
$sesid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

connectDB();
$sql ="select * from subscribe where uniqueuser = '$sesid'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
{
    $subscription = $row['subscription'];
    $lastviewed = $row['lastviewed'];
    $substart = $row['substart'];
    $sql3 = "select * from article 
        where uniqueuser = '$subscription' 
        and date_posted > '$lastviewed' 
        order by date_posted 
        desc limit 0, 7";

    $rsd3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    $newarticles = mysql_num_rows($rsd3);

    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsd3)) {
        $id  =$row3['id'];
        $title = $row3['title'];
        $uid = $row3['uniqueuser'];
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$uid'";  
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            $name = $row2['user_name'];
            echo "<b><a>{$name}</a></b> wrote an <a>article</a><br>";
        }
    }
} //END SUBSCRIBE
```

This outputs:

```
User A wrote an article (1th july)
User A wrote an article (2th july)
User A wrote an article (3th july)
User A wrote an article (4th july)
User B wrote an article (1th july)
User B wrote an article (2th july)
User B wrote an article (3th july)
User B wrote an article (4th july)
```

It orders it one user after another, even if user B's article has posted in between user A's posts.

Wanted output :

```
User A wrote an article (1th july)
User B wrote an article (1th july)
User A wrote an article (2th july)
User B wrote an article (2th july)
User A wrote an article (3th july)
User B wrote an article (3th july)
User A wrote an article (4th july)
User B wrote an article (4th july)
```

So how do i bunch it up and literate it ordered by date, regardless of what user wrote it?
My issue i think is because of the while loop on the subscribe query, but i dont know any other ways to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less simply join the 3 tables involved and sort by **a.date_posted**

```
$sql2 = "select a.* , u.user_name, a.id as article_id, u.id as user_id 
    from subscribe s
    join article a on s.subscription = a.uniqueuser AND s.lastviewed < a.date_posted
    join user u on a.uniqueuser = u.id
    where s.uniqueuser = '$sesid'
    order by a.date_posted 
    desc limit 0, 7";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $name = $row2['user_name'];
    $date = $row2['date_posted'];
// fetch the columns having the same name using aliases
$a_id = $row2['article_id'];
$u_id = $row2['user_id'];

    echo "<b><a>{$name}</a></b> wrote an <a>article</a>({$date})<br>";
}
```

EDIT

Fix condition s.lastviewed < a.date_posted

ADD about join

**Joins** between two or more table is a set of all combinations of all elements of the tables having the valid/true conditions (ON and WHERE)

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time! This seems to work! =) these join queries are still black magic to me, so i have to ask: If i need to fetch rows from for example the article table. How do i literate that?  Article has a row called id, which stores the article id. But row[id] returns the user's id instead of the article id i want. any idea? 

** made it work by doing  u.id as userid! =) **